# How to use static nested loops in cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, cypress

I am trying to automate one test scenario where i am first traversing pages one by one and on each page i am traversing list of elements until i find my desired element, but when my condition is met in the if statement i am setting a flag to stop both the loops, but the outer loop keeps on running till the last page even if my condition is already met at 2nd page can you guys please help me in this

my method

```
clickOnNextBtnUntilDisable() {
    cy.get(".MuiPagination-ul li button").last().invoke("text").as("lastPage");
    cy.get("@lastPage").then((lastPageText) => { 
      const index = parseInt(lastPageText, 10); // converting last page text into int.
      let flag = false;
      for (let i = 1; i < index; i++) {
        cy.get(".MuiGrid-justify-xs-space-evenly .MuiGrid-container > p").each(
          (el, index) => {
            if (el.text() === "Test Attribute Do not touch") {
              cy.log("Condition met");
              flag = true;
              return;
            }
          }
        );
        if (!flag) {
          cy.contains("Next").click();
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

my test

```
it("Adding question to existing attribute", function () {
    dashBoardPage.clickOnSwitchView();
    dashBoardPage.clickOnAttributes();
    attributesPage.clickOnNextBtnUntilDisable();
  });
```

Sharing UI Images for ref 1st page
[image]

2nd page and so on
[image]

Comment: Your issue is coming from mixing synchronous JS code (your `for` loop and `if/else`) and asynchronous Cypress code (your `cy.get().each()`). https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Mixing-Async-and-Sync-code

Also, why do you have to iterate through elements on each page instead of just grabbing the element directly and checking the text/enabled status? Can you provide an example HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Aliasing the flag**

You could use an alias to test your flag condition:

```js
let flag = false;
cy.wrap(flag).as('stop')

for (let i = 1; i < index; i++) {
  cy.get('@stop').then(stop =>
    if (!stop) {

        cy.get(".MuiGrid-justify-xs-space-evenly .MuiGrid-container > p").each(
        (el, index) => {
            if (el.text() === "Test Attribute Do not touch") {
              cy.log("Condition met");
              flag = true;
              cy.wrap(flag).as('stop')
              
              return          // <-- early exit for .each()
            }
          }
        )

        // also need the alias check here, since above .each() needs to finish
        cy.get('@stop').then(stop =>
          if (!stop) {
            cy.contains("Next").click();
          }
        })
```

This "coordinates" the static `for()` loop with the results of the dynamic queries inside the loop.

Without the line `cy.get('@stop').then(stop =>`, the code is enqueuing all the commands onto the queue before the command queue has started to run.

Comment: This works smooth, but i am not understanding what you actually did here, and how cypress works here synchronous code.

Comment: When you put a command like `cy.get('.MuiGrid-container > p')` in your test, it's not actually executed right away. The test code is just build the command queue, which is only executed *at the end of the block*. So a static for loop can't see the result `flag = true` because that occurs after the loop finishes.

Comment: But if you add  `cy.get('@stop').then(stop =>` this puts the check `if (!stop)` into the queue  before each `el.text() === "..."`, so if the previous iteration found the item, all the rest are stopped from running.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach, set the data with a fixture so that you know exactly what page your text is on.

Then your loops can be separate, and the **Next** action does not depend on `flag`.

```js
// Move to page directly
const index = 3                    // if text is on 4th page
for (let i = 1; i < index; i++) {
  cy.contains("Next").click()
}

// Find element on page
let flag = false;
cy.get(".MuiGrid-justify-xs-space-evenly .MuiGrid-container > p")
  .each((el) => {
     if (el.text() === "Test Attribute Do not touch") {
       cy.log("Condition met");
       flag = true;
       return;
     }
   })
  .should(() => expect(flag).to.eq(true))
```